# How to decrypt the modules of social engine?

Tags: socialengine

This is a controller of a module.how can write my own logic in the controller by decoding this. Can any body help me??

```
<?php //00489
// Copyright (c) 2008 Webligo Developments http://www.socialengine.com/license/

if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader'){  
  $__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));
  $__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');
  if(function_exists('dl')){
    @dl($__ln);
  }
  if(function_exists('_il_exec')){
    return _il_exec();
  }
  $__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;
  $__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));
  $__here=dirname(__FILE__);

  if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){         
    $__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));
    $__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));
  }
  $__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';
  $__i=strlen($__rd);
  while($__i--){
    if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){
      $__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;
      if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)) {
        $__ln=$__lp;break;
      }
    }
  }
  if(function_exists('dl')){
    @dl($__ln);
  }
}
else{
  die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");
}
if(function_exists('_il_exec')) {
  return _il_exec();
}
echo('<html> <body> The ionCube loader has not been installed. Click <a href="ioncube/loader-wizard.php">here</a> for help installing it, or contact your hosting provider. Please return to this page once complete. </body> </html>');
exit(199);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the decrypted modules when you buy a license from SocialEngine : https://www.socialengine.com/features/php

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have license. its illegal. Buy License

Comment: "thanks @Gaurav this is the trial version I am using I will buy the license "